# Select ALL in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have a table based on three drop down lists.  The first is a client list, the second is a date list and the third is a stage list.  The first two are single value lists.  I can only allow the user to select 1 from each of those lists.  The third list is a stage list.  This contains the values First,Final and Release.  My client has come back to me and asked if I can supply them with the ability to select all of the stages as an option.  Here is the query as I have it right now.  I have tried using (AnnotationDate IN (@Stage)) in place of (AnnotationDate = @Stage) but was unsuccessful.  Can anyone give me a helpful hint?

```
SELECT     AdDate, Page_ID, Status, AnnotationNumber, AnnotationBy, [Role Description], AnnotationDate, AnnotationType, BusinessUnit, ActualAgencyError, ErrorType, 
                      AnnotationComments, TeamComments, sgkComments, PA, Client, Activity, Support, Name, BusImpact
FROM         vwAgencyErrorOpen
WHERE     (Client = @Client) AND (AdDate = @Job) AND (AnnotationDate = @Stage)
ORDER BY Page_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `@Stage` Parameter to be multi-seletion.

[image: MultiSelect Parameter]

Then remove the `(AnnotationDate = @Stage)` clause from the query.

And then set up a filter on your dataset as below:

[image: Dataset Filter]

You can then select all of your options.

[image: Select all]

Comment: This works just like my query.  What it does not address is how do I account for all stages?

Comment: This did work.  Thank you.  I now just have to work on getting the information into the title properly.

Comment: No problem. I think you can use `Join(Parameters!Name.Value,",")` or similar to join the selected values into a comma separated string.